# MS DOS command line for internet sharing

Tags: networking, command-line, cmd, windows-8.1

I have internet connection through adaptaterA.
I'm looking for a command line to share internet connection from adaptaterA to adaptaterB.

Answer (score 0):

If your AdapterB is a Wifi Adapter (you aren't telling)
You could use *netsh*s wlan start hostednetwork. 
See netsh help for further information on how to use netsh. 
The help tells you also how to configure hosted networks and - with some research - how to share other types of connections. 
Netsh is batchable.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but actually I'm looking for the command to share internet not the one to create hotspot. And my adapterB is my wifi Adapter. Basically I'm looking for command that could replace going to the "network and sharing" and then tick "allow internet sharing" from the AdapterA to AdapterB,

Comment: This could be done with simple route additions. Because netsh doesn't support internet sharing since win7 I will have a look for a batch solution and will post it as an answer.

Comment: Fine! Would you share it to us as an answer?